# Wordpress subdirectory installation, possible DNS issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns

Our company website uses Wordpress and I am looking to set up a second installation in a subdirectory of the main site. The second site has been set up and seems to work fine externally, but inside our network(which has the same domain as the website) the secondary site does not load. For example;

- www.systechinfo.com - loads fine
- www.systechinfo.com/wp-admin - loads fine
- www.systechinfo.com/emc - doesn't load internally, but loads
  fine externally

We are using the www redirect hack internally to get the main site to load, but I am not sure if this is a DNS issue or a redirect issue on the HTACCESS. Please advise. Thank you for your time.

Comment: While I am still curious to understand why this was not working, we decided to go with a second domain for our purposes. Mods can close this if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the new subdirectory has to upload the files and install wordpress. The other option is to create multisite. http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Your site is already running.